# jasmine-reporters not working with grunt-protractor-runner?

Tags: jenkins, report, jasmine

i use the grunt-protractor-runner to run my protractor tests with jenkins. Now jenkins needs the xml output to inform me about the test run.

I have installed jasmine-reporters. I have read all other topics and i am sure the installation is correct but i do not receive any output files from it...

Could you please help me?

```
   require('jasmine-reporters');
           jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
               new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter('configurations/protractor/xmloutput', true, true));
```

i have installed jasmine-reporters version 1.0.1

Comment: Update: Now my setup creates a xml report only when all tests are running successfully... But, if any teststep or asset fails it does not create a xml report...

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup using grunt-protractor-runner, but I don't generate an XML for Jenkins. You could use the [protractor-html-screenshot-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter)

This will generate an html report. I then configured Jenkins to publish the HTML report using the [HTML Reporter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) which gives a tidy link on the page and displays the results in a tabular format.

The conf.js needs the following two snippets

```
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');
var path = require('path');
```

and

```
    onPrepare: function() {
    var directory = __dirname;
    browser.baseUrl = process.argv[3];
    htmlFilePath = directory + '\\reports\\';

    // Add a screenshot reporter and store screenshots:
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
    baseDirectory: directory + '\\reports',
    preserveDirectory: true
    }));
   }
```

Comment: I now updated to jasmine 2.2 und protractor 1.7.0 and jasmine-reportsers 2.0.4. But i still receive no reports (from both modules)... Any ideas?

Comment: `The code is here:
require('jasmine-reporters');
        var junitReporter = new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
            savePath: 'xmloutput',
            consolidateAll: false
        });
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(junitReporter);

        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
            baseDirectory: 'reports',
            takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true
        }));`

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer. I post it just in case someone run into this and somehow get link to this question. In our case, we are trying to use teamcity reporter instead of XML reporter. The problem may be caused by your protractor is running with Jasmine 1.X while your jasmine-reporters' version is 2.X. Try to downgrade jasmine reporter to 1.1.0 may solve your problem.